# Is there a specific word for "goes without being said"?

Tags: meaning

I have encountered this problems quite often and usually got stuck trying to nail down what I want to say. English is not my native language so I wonder if any native speakers could explain this to me.

An example for this is when I say "I think this author is female because she says..." When I assume the author is female through details of the provided text, I have [the word that I am looking for that can substitute "goes without being said"] stereotyped those details as restrictive female or male.

Another example is when person A uses their hands to pick up food and person B sees that. B then asks A why. A says "I don't know. I think it is [the word]. People of my country do that without explanation."

Comment: I think you're looking for *"implicitly"* for your first example. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work for your second example.

Comment: @PeterShor: actually, the second definition given in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implicit fits the second example quite well.

Comment: The technical term is _presupposed_. The phenomenon is known as [_Presupposition_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf).

Comment: At least one answer is obvious...

Comment: @MarkBannister Perhaps technically, but in practice it sounds strange. Consider that (in my opinion, at least) the most succinct word for the second example is *natural* or perhaps *instinct*, which feels odd to replace with *implicit*. I think *implicit* tends to be used in the context of expression, e.g. in the definition you cite OED uses the example of a school's ethos, i.e. their expression of their beliefs and values. In other words, something can be called *implicit* if it can be *implied*, and I don't think the act of implication fits the asker's second example at all.

Comment: 'Apodeictic' means 'self-evidently true'. 'Axiomatic' means 'self-evident' or 'unquestionable'. But the second is very formal, the first rarefied.

Comment: You'd probably need to rephrase your sentences to make it fit, but I'm surprised nobody has yet suggested **tacit**.

Comment: I think the verb "to imply" sounds better that the adjective "implicit" in the first example. "I think the details of (or in) the provided text imply that this author is female, for example when she says ...". But the second example is different. In the first one, you are making a deduction from the information you have. In the second one, person A is just copying what everybody else around him did in his country, not thinking out for himself how to pick up the food. It is "Customary", traditional", "cultural", or "conventional" to pick up the food that way.

Comment: I think maybe "infer" fits better with the first one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are "self-evident" and "self-explanatory" the same?

Comment: It goes without being said...

Comment: @RexYuan What do dictionaries say?

Comment: FYI, "goes without saying" is more idiomatic than "~being said"

Comment: Not at all. What you're Asking about does not and never could "go without being said." Other examples might work.

You might think - even rightly - an author was male or female and until you could prove that by reference to the text, you would never be entitled to assert that belief. 

An example might indeed be "… this author is female because she says..." but how could that ever "go without being said"?

Assuming an author is female through details of the text, you have either your own prejudice or a great deal of justification to work with. Which would work better for you?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I suggest the word [implicit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implicit) (*implicitly*, in the first example in the question):

> 1. Suggested though not directly expressed: *comments seen as implicit criticism of the policies*

...

> 2. (implicit in) Always to be found in; essentially connected with: *the values implicit in the school ethos*

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew this word but never thought of it this way!

Answer (score 23):

I think there is a bit of a disconnect between the question and the examples given. That being said I think there are several words that can be used depending on context.

One possibility is the word **[obvious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obvious)** with emphasis on the second definition.

> Merriam-Webster
>
> > 1 : easy to see or notice
> >
> > 2 : easy for the mind to understand or recognize

I think this can be used somewhat interchangeably with the phrase "goes without saying/being said".

Ex: After seeing the wreckage it goes without saying that the ship ran aground.

Ex: After seeing the wreckage it was obvious that the ship ran aground.

Also take a look at [this post](http://grammarist.com/usage/goes-without-saying/) on Grammarist.

> ### Goes without saying
>
> It’s easy to be hard on goes without saying—if
>   something goes without saying, why say it?—but the phrase sometimes
>   works well as a wordy way of saying **obviously**, and it can be useful
>   for emphasis or transition.

Also, as pointed out by Mark the word implicit can be used in the examples given by the OP and also in many cases interchangeably with "it goes without saying/being said". I would emphasize the first definition since it captures the idea of something being known without being expressed.

[implicit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/implicit)

> adjective im·plic·it \im-ˈpli-sət\ 
>    1 : understood though not clearly
>   or directly stated

Comment: +1, for obvious. However, apparent- leaves the door open for a little ambiguity.

Comment: I have edited to reference other answers for alternatives instead of using the apparent/unambiguous examples.

Answer (score 10):

I would say "self-evidently" works well in both cases. Similar to "obvious" and related synonyms, but with the added nuance of implying the obviousness requires no external or a priori knowledge of the subject at hand.

Comment: Perhaps "evident" would be cleaner.

Comment: To my eye/ear, "evidently" in that context reads less like "obviously" and related words, and more like "apparently," with the connotation of "as it turns out."

Answer (score 8):

"Evidently" is an alternative.

**evidently** *adverb*
used for saying that something is obvious

Comment: Perhaps *self-evident* woudl better capture the sense.

Comment: +1, evident was my first choice, then "conspicuous" hit my senses.

Answer (score 6):

*[Tacit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.reference.com%2Fbrowse%2Ftacit&ei=pHWEVYuDBcuo-QGi3rjIDQ&usg=AFQjCNE8y_D6nt5BiF3OjnO9VTqWK9Cj-A&sig2=TOzLj-qxbUSLlzSoZL43HQ&bvm=bv.96339352,d.cWw)* is also an interesting and somewhat uncommon choice:

> tac·it ˈtasət/
>
> adjective
>
> 1. understood or implied without being stated.

Answer (score 4):

**Conspicuous** - [obvious to the eye or mind](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/obvious)

> Conspicuous can mean very obvious to the eye (like something that is
> conspicuous from a distance). If you are doing something wrong, it's
> wise not to be conspicuous about it!

(vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your sentences, I am not sure that your description of the word matches what you are trying to say.  I think maybe you want a word for a behavior that is a cultural or social norm that is done without really thinking about it. It is done automatically. It is habitual.

For the first sentence I would use **unknowingly, unconsciously, subconsciously, or inadvertently.**  A vote for **implicitly** too if the focus on society versus the individual's being unaware they are doing it. For the second sentence I would state it as follows: It is done **subconsciously, unconsciously, out of habit, or automatically.**

I am a sociologist, but not a specialist in social interaction and culture.  If you find a sociology question site, there may be an expert who can give you more specific terminology on unintentionally producing and reproducing cultural norms, and perhaps, there is a specific word that refers to the events in your sentences.  Being a former instructor, I don't think using multiple words to describe the behavior is a real problem.  In this case, I might use **subconscious social or cultural norm,** probably not in your sentences, but I think this is the behavior to which you are referring.

Sorry to be long-winded, hope this helps or points you onward.

Answer (score 4):

In your second example:

> Another example is when person A uses hands to pick up foods and person B sees that. B then asks A why. A says that "I don't know. I think it is [the word]. People of my country do that without explanation."

**[customary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/customary)** or **[the done thing](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-done-thing)** might be good substitutions for [the word]. I don't think you will find a single word that will work in both of your examples.

Comment: I'd say 'customary' is the best fit for OP's second example.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "goes without being said" means that most people know and agree with what is being said.

Example:

> It goes without being said that all cats love tuna.
>
> Everyone knows that all cats lover tuna.

Synonyms for this would include:

- It's implied
- It's well known
- It's obvious
- It's well understood

If what is being said really is well understood and agreed upon by people, it should be possible and accurate to say the sentence without the idiom at all. For example:

> It goes without saying that war is violent.
>
> Everyone knows that war is violent.
>
> War is violent.

Comment: Just to nitpick: "X is true" and "Everyone knows that X is true" are not the same thing. There are lots of things that are true but that many people don't know. "Minsk is the capital of Belarus." A true statement. But I'm quite sure that there are many people in the world who do not know this.

Comment: @Jay it goes without being said that what you are saying is true. (Sorry, couldn't resist.) Like any instance of an idiom, it would need to be evaluated to see if it means something more. Another example would be when this expression is used for a widely held believe that isn't true or is half true (e.g. "Everyone knows that Pluto is the 9th planet in the Solar System")

Comment: Sure. There are lots of things that "everyone knows" that ain't so. We laugh at dumb things people believed hundreds of years ago. I'm sure that hundreds of years from now people will be laughing at the crazy things that all those dumb 21st century people believed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on just how you mean it, words that occur to me are "obvious" and "assumed".

"Obvious" indicates that a statement is true, and that almost everyone quickly recognizes that it is true. "Everyone knows that water is wet." "It is obvious that water is wet."

"Assumed" indicates that most people believe that a statement is true, but can be used whether the speaker thinks it is true or not. "People assume that I like whiskey just because I'm Irish." Maybe you do and maybe you don't, but everyone thinks that.

You could also say "it's common knowledge that ...", but that's another phrase and not one word.

Answer (score 2):

[Naturally](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/naturally)

> of course; as would be expected; needless to say.

If you prefix something with `"naturally"` then you are implying that it would have been expected.

`"Natural"` also works in your second example, as eating certain foods with your hands may seem natural to some people and not others.

Comment: I am not a native speaker of English, but I think _naturally_ is a suitable word in that context as it means _of course; as would be expected; needless to say_ as per your link. +1

Answer (score 2):

If something "goes without being said" it's ***given***.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but the distribution of this sense of 'given' is, I think, rather idiosyncratic. 'It's [a] given that ...' and 'We can take it as given that ...' probably account for a high percentage of its occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

[manifestly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manifestly) *adverb*.

> In a way that is clear or obvious to the eye or mind

[natch](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/natch) *adverb, informal*.

> Naturally; as may be expected

Answer (score 1):

One of the first words that came to mind was *implicit*, but after reading the examples, I think I would use *understandably* and *normal*, or *commonplace*, for the first and second examples, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It seems if it goes without saying, then it is "understood," depending on the exact phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

Plus one for "obviously" but depending on the context, **necessarily** would sometimes work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *ipso facto*:

> directly translated as "by the fact itself,"[1] which means that a certain phenomenon is a direct consequence, a resultant effect, of the action in question

Answer (score 0):

I propose another alternative: `axiomatic`:

Of the nature of an axiom or admitted first principle; self-evident; indisputably true. [(OED)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14047?redirectedFrom=axiomatic#eid)

Also similar but not exactly correct: `tautological`:

Of an argument or definition: merely restating in different words the very thing which is to be explained, shown, or defined [(OED)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/198199?redirectedFrom=tautological#eid)

Answer (score -1):

what about

> to state the obvious

or

> stating the obvious